# Why getting no protocol error on OSX trying to use a dataflavor that this transferable has?

Tags: java, macos

Reporting this error when trying to copy and paste an image from amazon, although we check the transferable object support a particular dataflavor, it fails when try and use that data flavour to get a url. Ive not seen thsi error before and recently moved to Java 1.8.0_20 so Im assuming the issues lies with Java 8 ?

```
 java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <array>
        <string>http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41NTPXC8EHL.jpg</string>
        <string></string>
    </array>
    </plist>
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CDataTransferer.translateBytes(CDataTransferer.java:135)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardTransferable$DataFactory.getTransferData(ClipboardTransferable.java:71)
    at sun.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardTransferable.getTransferData(ClipboardTransferable.java:168)
```

Code Extract is

```
public static DataFlavor imageUrlFlavor =  new DataFlavor("application/x-java-url;class=java.net.URL");
public void getImage(Transferable trans)

            if(trans.isDataFlavorSupported(FileDropTarget.imageUrlFlavor))
            {
                imageUrl  = (URL) trans.getTransferData(FileDropTarget.imageUrlFlavor);
            }
```

Comment: You are casting that XML to URL. Try get as a String and parse to get the <string> attribute

Answer (score 0):

***Not a satisfying answer***
You can list all `DataFlavor`s placed on the clipboard [trans.getDataFlavors()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html#getTransferDataFlavors--); in general a copy places several flavors like plain-text and styled-text.

The alternative

```
public static DataFlavor imageUrlFlavor = 
    new DataFlavor(URL.class, "application/x-java-url");
```

probably fails too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that OS X wraps copied data into plist/xml, so it breaks your parsing. Do you copy images directly from browser or from other application?

I've tried to copy images and urls from Chrome and Safari in a simple swing app on my mac (OS X 10.9.5, Java 8u20) and I always got text/plain or image/x-java-image mimetypes, never application/x-java-url or xml-wrapped content.

```
 Transferable clipData = clipboard.getContents(clipboard);
 if (clipData != null) {
     try {
           for (DataFlavor f : clipData.getTransferDataFlavors()) {
              System.out.println("f = " + f);
           }

           if (clipData.isDataFlavorSupported(imageUrlFlavor)) {
               URL url = (URL) clipData.getTransferData(imageUrlFlavor);

               System.out.println("Got url:");
               System.out.println(url);
           }

      } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
          System.err.println("Flavor unsupported: " + ufe);
      } catch (IOException ioe) {
          System.err.println("Data not available: " + ioe);
      }
 }
```

I also tried to do this with drag'n'drop and got the same result:

```
public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
    System.out.println("drop");
    dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE);
    Transferable trans = dtde.getTransferable();
    boolean gotData = false;
    // try for application/x-java-url flavor
    try {
        if (trans.isDataFlavorSupported(urlFlavor)) {
            URL url = (URL) trans.getTransferData(urlFlavor);
            System.out.println ("got an url: " + url);
            statusField.setText(url.toString());
            statusField.setCaretPosition(0);
            gotData = true;
        } else if (trans.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor)) {
            String s =
                    (String) trans.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            System.out.println("Got text: " + s);
            statusField.setText(s);
            gotData = true;
        } else {
            dumpDataFlavors(trans);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("gotData is " + gotData);
        dtde.dropComplete(gotData);
    }
}
```